# Training on Google Colab, Unity Environment hangs with Multiprocessing.py

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to use Colab to training an environment. I built the environment on server mode for Linux and managed to install the dependencies on Colab, which was a bit tricky. I have no errors reseting the environment but after the first env.step() the kernel just hangs. This is the error message I get after I interrupt the kernel:

```
/content/ml-agents/ml-agents/mlagents/envs/environment.py in step(self, vector_action, memory, text_action, value)
390 
391             outputs = self.communicator.exchange(
--> 392                 self._generate_step_input(vector_action, memory, text_action, value))
393             if outputs is None:
394                 raise KeyboardInterrupt

/content/ml-agents/ml-agents/mlagents/envs/rpc_communicator.py in exchange(self, inputs)
 94         message.unity_input.CopyFrom(inputs)
 95         self.unity_to_external.parent_conn.send(message)
---> 96         output = self.unity_to_external.parent_conn.recv()
 97         if output.header.status != 200:
 98             return None

/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py in recv(self)
248         self._check_closed()
249         self._check_readable()
--> 250         buf = self._recv_bytes()
251         return _ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
252 

/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py in _recv_bytes(self, maxsize)
405 
406     def _recv_bytes(self, maxsize=None):
--> 407         buf = self._recv(4)
408         size, = struct.unpack("!i", buf.getvalue())
409         if maxsize is not None and size > maxsize:

/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py in _recv(self, size, read)
377         remaining = size
378         while remaining > 0:
--> 379             chunk = read(handle, remaining)
380             n = len(chunk)
381             if n == 0:

KeyboardInterrupt:
```

I'm guessing there's a problem with the threads here on Colab, maybe a timeout? I honestly have no idea since I have zero experience with multiprocessing. Maybe an issue with the packages versions? Has anyone managed to run the UnityEnvironment python API on Colab?

The issue occurs after one or two calls to env.step() on the UnityEnvironment. The kernel just hangs there, that's when I stop the kernel(hence the keyboard interrupt).

Thanks a lot for the help!